# WYGWAM and IE11 issues on Publish

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic, wygwam, better-workflow, internetexplorer

I am running a site that uses the following EE 2.7.3, MSM 2.1.6, Better Workflow 1.6.4.2  and WYGWAM 3.3.

When a page is edited in IE11, when I go to save the page from any tab apart from the 'Publish' tab. A number of rows of  `'<p>&nbsp;</p>'` are injected into the end of each wygwam field.

Is this something anybody has seen or fixed?

Comment: I have seen it, but don't have a fix. I recommended my client to use Chrome because of other issues. But still, this is a bug. You can file the bug at http://pixelandtonic.com/support